# react-materialize DatePicker allow empty date when init

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, momentjs, materialize

I am trying to do a frontend component in **react** with **react-materialize**.

I have a `datePicker` to pick up a date but I am struggling to have it `init` with an **empty value**.

It shows `Invalid Date` at startup. It works but might disturb the users so I would like to solve this issue and showing the `placeholder` instead...

Any help is more than welcome.

Thank you!

Here is the code:
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-voice-05fz5?file=/src/App.js)

PS: I am very new to React, I guess the code speaks for itself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `onSelect` prop of the `DatePicker` and pass your date handler function to it. That could look something like this:

```
<DatePicker
  onSelect={this.handleBirthdateChange}
  placeholder="Date de naissance"
  // Other props... 
/>
```

Also remove your `value` and `onChange` props from the `DatePicker` if you choose this approach.